# how to execute dos command with options in java

Tags: java, command-line

I want to execute dos based external command through java program if there there is any way please help me

Comment: Java runs on DOS?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
    String[] options = new String[]{"option1", "option2"};
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("command", options);
```

Answer (score 2):

The following bit of code will run the dir command, and then print out for you as well as error. Taken and adapted from (http://www.devdaily.com/java/edu/pj/pj010016)

```
import java.io.*;

public class JavaRunCommand {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        String s = null;

        try {

        // run the Windows command (dir)
            // using the Runtime exec method:
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("dir");

            BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new 
                 InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

            BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new 
                 InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));

            // read the output from the command
            System.out.println("Here is the standard output of the command:\n");
            while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(s);
            }

            // read any errors from the attempted command
            System.out.println("Here is the standard error of the command (if any):\n");
            while ((s = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(s);
            }

            System.exit(0);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("exception happened
- here's what I know: ");
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(-1);
        }
    } }
```